# How to get a value of dynamically generated checkbox inside Model in Post Method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I need to pass back a collection of checked checkboxes on form submit.
The problem is, the checkboxes are not part of the model, they're generated by jquery after the user performs some action. the check boxes are coming properly on page.
How can i get a checked property inside my Model at post event.

```
 @model Models.MainModule
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Detail", "SomeControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
          @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.SubCheckList)
         <div id="CheckList"></div>

        }
```

Jquery for checkbox:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ModID").change(function () {
            var ModId = $('#ModID').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/SomeController/SomeAction",
                data: { Mid: ModID },
                datatype: "json",
                traditional: true,

                success: function (data) {
                    $('#CheckList').empty();
                    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        var li = $('<li><input type="checkbox" name="' + key + '" id="' + value.subID + '"/>' +
                            '<label for="' + key + '"></label></li>');
                        li.find('label').text(value.subName);
                        $('#CheckList').append(li);
                    });
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

Model class

```
 namespace Models
    {
        public class MainModule
        {
            public int MainID { get; set; }
            public string MainName { get; set; }
      public List<MyModule> SubCheckList { get; set; }  
        }

 public MainModule()
        {
            this.SubCheckList = new List<MyModule>();
        }       

    public class MyModule
        {
            public int id { get; set; }  

            public string name { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Detail(MyModule myModuleObj)
  {
    GetViewBagData();
     return View();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through AJAX form submit.

First add a name for your form as your requirement. For ex, 'formMainModule'

First add a class 'chkBxClass' to each checkbox. This is for getting checkbox values which are checked later.

In jquery

```
var checkedIds = $('.chkBxClass:checkbox:checked').map(function () { return this.value; }).get().join(','); 

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('#formMainModule').serialize() + '&checkedIds=' + checkedIds,
    url: '/SomeControllerName/Detail',
    success: function (result) {
             }
    });
```

In controller,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Detail(MyModule myModuleObj, string[] checkedIds)
{
     // Here you can add checked ids to your module
}
```

Comment: I know i can do with array but i want to directly bind with model property.

Comment: The value i want to get when the final submit button is clicked and it calls below method. [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Detail(MyModule myModuleObj)
  {
    GetViewBagData();
     return View();
  }